# Include files outside WordPress directory

Tags: wordpress

I have a directory /blog/ where I have WordPress installed. I'm creating a theme to handle the blog within that directory.

I have all my styles in /style/, includes in /includes/, and scripts in /scripts/. There has to be a way for me to include these files into my WordPress) theme. So basically, I want to include my stylesheet that the rest of the site (non-WordPress) is using. Yes, I'm aware WordPress requires a style.css in the theme root. However, I want to use this for other things as well. Such as including my header and footer, and also my compiled external JavaScript.

```
index.php
/style/
/blog/
    /wp-content/
        /themes/
            /my-theme/
/includes/
/scripts/
```

Summary: How do I access style / includes / scripts directories from within the WordPress theme?

Answer (score 1):

In your functions.php you can do the following:

```
function yourtheme_enqueue_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'unique-id', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/styles/style.css', false );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'unique-id', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/scripts/filename.js', false );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','yourtheme_enqueue_scripts');
```

Replace yourtheme, unique-id, style.css, filename.js with whatever is suitable for your situation.

Comment: That only works if you are not in a shared server environment.

Comment: It's a bit hacky but using the full url should work. `wp_enqueue_style( 'unique-id',  'https://www.yoursite.com/styles/style.css', false );

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a symlink inside the Wordpress directory that points to the file outside of it.

Comment: I'm not sure about the term symlink, are you just referring to absolute/relative paths?

Comment: What operating system is your server using? Assuming it's a 'nix type, the `ln -s` command creates a *symbolic link* to the target file so that it appears to exist in the referring directory.  I think winDoze has an equivalent construct, but I don't recall what it is.

Comment: just clear in which file you want to use include those files I mean in header.php or footer.php

Answer (score 0):

You can do this inside any PHP file:

```php
<?php include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/path/to/file.php'); ?>
```